# Is there any benefit to not using a namespace and using the class with the namespace instead?

Tags: c#, namespaces, using

What I mean is instead of going

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
[...]
Regex.IsMatch(string, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

it's also possible to do

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(string, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Is there any benefit to either option besides readability?

Comment: The first option is cleaner and you have less type to do. The last one is an option to use when you have methods with the same name in two different namespaces, to disambiguate

Comment: @RatzMouze yes, it does, I just wasn't able to find it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets compiled into the same  thing, but:

1. Code is easier to read
2. Less code to type
3. Developer can quickly see what usings are used in class file